# How to get 1 to 20 row from 5000 rows in a single query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get 1 to 20 rows from 5000 rows. I was tried to make a single query then Insert into a dummy table after that I count rows from dummy table
and get 1 to 20 rows. it's worked but it's take more time. So guy's you have any idea about this so please tell me.

```
SELECT * FROM CRM_Contacts
```

Comment: Which version of sql server you are using ?

Comment: I am using SQL-Serve 2012.

Comment: @user8380225 you Should Learn Basic MSSQL  from https://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`OFFSET Fetch`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx) in `Sql Server 2012`

```
SELECT * 
FROM CRM_Contacts
ORDER BY Order_column 
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

for older versions use `Row_Number`

```
select * from 
(
Select *, Row_Number()Over(Order by Order_column) as Rn
From Yourtable
) a
Where Rn between 1 and 20
```

If it is always top 20 then

```
SELECT top 20 * 
FROM CRM_Contacts
ORDER BY Order_column
```

Comment: @user8380225 - Second query will work in all the versions

Comment: @user8380225 - Are you looking for pagination or just top 20 records ?

Comment: Yes I looking for pagination Like 1,2,3,4 query( 0 to 20, 21 to 40, 41 to 60 ).

Comment: @user8380225 - Then use first query for `Sql Server 2012` and above. For older version use `Row_Number` approach